# UITableView with 8 inherited cell type

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, uitableview

I have a *UITableView*, with 8 differents type of cell. Those custom cell have some design in commom (like a upper left icon, a title, a subtitle...). However, under those common features, each cell is different. In order to have less to maintain, my 8 cells inherits from a default abstract cell with the commons IBOutlet.

Now my question is : what is the best, most proper way to do this?

At first, I thought of using **registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:** but this means 8 different xib. In this case, if one of the common design feature change, I would need to go trought all 8 xibs to change the same thing. I thnik it's not very productive and clean.

I thought also of **registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:** but this methods does not create the cell with a nib, so I would need to do everything programmatically.

The solution could be have one common xib, different registered class in the tableview, and those will be responsible for using their own custom design. But I can't see how to achieve this with those two previous methods.

Comment: Did you find any elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single nib file with 8 different UITableViewCell subclasses. You should be able to use `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` and inside the class (which subclasses UITableViewCell) you make use of the nib file. If it is not clear I'll try to provide some code.